# Amazon AWS Lambda error: Upload too large: 1070404 bytes exceeds limit of 1048576

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-kinesis

We are using kinesis stream to segregate logs from loggroup and send it to the Lambda function if the filter condition satisfies. We deployed it into production and it is all working fine till now. But now we are getting below error from Lambda while processing the event. Please help if you have encountered similar or something you are aware of. Thanks.

```
2021-07-15T07:15:47.997Z    4bcfa467-81ea-4b7f-9db1-dea83ad02679    ERROR   Invoke Error    {
    "errorType": "InvalidParameterException",
    "errorMessage": "Upload too large: 1070404 bytes exceeds limit of 1048576",
    "code": "InvalidParameterException",
    "message": "Upload too large: 1070404 bytes exceeds limit of 1048576",
    "time": "2021-07-15T07:15:47.996Z",
    "requestId": "e438a664-baa2-4e46-97bf-7a47f2d4b5ae",
    "statusCode": 400,
    "retryable": false,
    "retryDelay": 83.5828195895287,
    "stack": [
        "InvalidParameterException: Upload too large: 1070404 bytes exceeds limit of 1048576",
        "    at Request.extractError (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/protocol/json.js:52:27)",
        "    at Request.callListeners (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:106:20)",
        "    at Request.emit (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:78:10)",
        "    at Request.emit (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:688:14)",
        "    at Request.transition (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)",
        "    at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)",
        "    at /var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10",
        "    at Request.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:38:9)",
        "    at Request.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:690:12)",
        "    at Request.callListeners (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:116:18)"
    ]
}
```

Comment: How do you inject records to the stream? Your are exeeding the limit of 1MB.

Comment: Kinesis can join multiple records together into one string. Take a look at data coming out of your stream, and if it's the case then implementing separation of records can help

Comment: We are actually using chunk library to limit the rows processed per batch/call assuming each event to be 2 kb approx, we are processing 500 records.

Comment: @Manjunath well it sounds like your records are slightly bigger than 2kb?

Comment: Hmm. Nice reflection though. We will reduce the record batch size and try

Comment: Your input seems to be true. Reduced the records per batch to 100 and it started working. Thanks

Comment: Nice! Also, you can try to compress the record size before you pass it on to the lambda - if you see this happen in future again!